# Is reassigning a std vector to default constructor vector a good way to erase?

Tags: c++, vector

There are so many questions and answers about clearing an `std::vector` and I'm wondering why, in all the ones I read, no one just says:

`existingVector = std::vector<whatever>();`

Is this not a simple way to clear a vector?

Comment: Why not simply use `existingVector.clear()`? It's even less to type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ see my comment to one of the answers

Comment: I guess the question lacks some detail on what you really want to do (e.g. reset the capacity). Please [edit] the question to include these details (I could do that too, but I am afraid to confuse it even further).

Comment: Actually, your code has a better chance of giving you exactly what you want, as an rvalue assignment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning is okay, but an optimizing implementation may be allowed to hold on to the raw memory buffer, to avoid reallocation.

Conventional wisdom for forcefully freeing the vector, is "swapping with a temporary":

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main() {

    std::vector<int> a(256);

    std::vector<int>().swap(a);

    std::cout << a.size() << " / " << a.capacity();

    return 0;
}
```

The above will *always* print `0 / <minimum_capacity_for_vec_impl>` because the vectors *must* swap their internal buffers. The temporary is then immediately destroyed, freeing the memory along with it.

---

`<minimum_capacity_for_vec_impl>` Will *usually* be 0, since the default constructor is `noexcept`, and by that virtue shuoldn't do dynamic memory allocation. But Library implementors can be creative sometimes with their optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed simple, but there is a simpler and more straightforward way:

```
existingVector.clear();
```

You could also do:

```
existingVector.resize(0);
```

But I like the first approach as it does exactly what it says it does.

Similarly, I prefer checking `if(myVec.empty())` instead of `if(myVec.size() == 0)`

**Update:** If you want a "true reset", i.e. you not only want the size to become 0 but also the capacity then there are a couple of things you could do.

1. shrink to fit

   ```
   vec.clear();
   vec.shrink_to_fit();
   ```

As the comments correctly point out though, shrink_to_fit, too, is a non-binding request which the compiler may ignore.

2. swap with a newly constructed vector

   ```
   vector<whatever>().swap(vec);
   ```

Comment: clear is simple but not a full erase, since it leaves memory available, right?

Comment: @Jerome: It may, and in practice it does, but the same applies to your approach. See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is a 'non-binding' request. Which makes it about as weak and pointless as `std::random_device` from a portability perspective:(

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is non-binding because the standard doesn't want to require an exact fit on an arbitrary size. For example, if you have a vector of 7 chars, the shrink is allowed to  result in a capacity of 8 or 16 bytes if that's the allocation sizes the memory manager offers.